# Can I use names from a list/dataframe, to be recognised as list/dataframe name within R script for a loop function?

Tags: r, parsing, for-loop, variables, type-conversion

I'd like to use a loop function to recognise names from a list/dataframe as an actual list/dataframe name in the R script (for data analysis or manipulation).
I will create some pseudo data to try to help show what i'm trying to do.

Here is code to create 3 lists

```
height <- sample(120:200,200,TRUE)
weight <- sample(40:140,200,TRUE)
income <- sample(20000:200000,200, TRUE)
```

This code creates a list containing those list names

```
vars <- c("height","weight","income")
```

The code below doesn't run, but I would like to use a loop code like this, where it takes the name from the list position and uses it in script as a list name. Thus it's using the name to calculate the mean, and it's using the name to create a new object.

```
for (i in 1:3) 
 {mean_**vars[i]** = mean(**vars[i]**) }
```

The result should be 3 objects "mean_height", "mean_weight", "mean_income" which contain the mean scores

I'm not so much interested in the calculating of mean scores, I'm interested in the ability to use the names from the list. I want to be able to expand this to other analyses that are repetitive.

Apologies if above hasn't been articulated too well, I'm quite new to R, so I hope it makes some sense.

Any help will be most useful, or if you can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for, where `lapply` applies the `mean` function to each of the items in `vars` (a list of dataframes). Note that you want to make the list of dataframes using the variable names.

```
height <- sample(120:200,200,TRUE)
weight <- sample(40:140,200,TRUE)
income <- sample(20000:200000,200, TRUE)

vars <- list(height, weight, income)

lapply(vars, function(x) mean(x))
```

Then create an output dataframe using that:

```
df1 <- data.frame(lapply(vars, function(x) mean(x)))

colnames(df1) <- c("mean_height", "mean_weight", "mean_income")

df1
```

---

From your additional comment, using `vars <- list(height, weight, income)` should allow you do this:

```
mean(height)
mean(vars[[1]])

[1] 160.48
[1] 160.48
```

---

This should work to output dynamically named variables:

```
vars <- list(height = height, weight = weight, income = income)

for (i in names(vars)){
  assign(paste("mean_", i, sep = ""), mean(vars[[i]]))
}

mean_height
mean_weight
mean_income

[1] 163.28
[1] 90.465
[1] 109686.5
```

However, I'd suggest not programming that way since it can cause issues and it's not very scalable. E.g., you could end up with 10000 variables.

Comment: thanks for that, this is very helpful. It's not exactly what i was looking for but definitely can use it. I've added additional comment.

Comment: @H.Cheung Ohh okay. I added an edit where I think `mean(vars[[1]])` is what you want after making the list of dataframes. The `[[` may be what you're missing there.

Comment: @H.Cheung Okay, I've added some to the answer

Answer (score 1):

A more common approach in R is to use lists of data, rather than separate variables.

Like this:

```
# make this reproducible
set.seed(123)

# make an empty list for the data
raw_data <- list()

# then fill the list. The data can be of varying length in a list.
raw_data$height <- sample(120:200,200,TRUE)
raw_data$weight <- sample(40:140,200,TRUE)
raw_data$income <- sample(20000:200000,200, TRUE)
```

Then looping becomes a one-liner and your names are preserved, using the `*apply` family of functions:

```
mean_data <- lapply(raw_data, mean)

# print that
mean_data
```

```
$height
[1] 159.06

$weight
[1] 90.83

$income
[1] 114000.7
```

Note what we *didn't* have to do:

- know the number of variables.
- have variables all the same length.
- build a loop and keep track of names.

All handled automagically. Nice.

Comment: thanks for that, this is very helpful. It's not exactly what i was looking for but definitely can use it. I've added additional comment

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is something like below, which produces three objects into your global environment for the means of `weight`, `height`, and `income` from list `list`, i.e.,

```
list2env(setNames(Map(mean,lst),paste0("mean_",names(lst))),envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

**DATA**

```
height <- sample(120:200,200,TRUE)
weight <- sample(40:140,200,TRUE)
income <- sample(20000:200000,200, TRUE)

lst <- list(height,weight,income)
```